# Inverter Upgrade

Tags: mosfet, inverter, waveform, sine, powermosfet

I have 600VA, 12V Pure Sine Wave Inverter (Atleast under no load, its pure) having 8 IRF3205 Mosfets in total. (In full bridge configurtion)

I have modified its shunt. Now it do not give overload error even when operated at 1000VA (Tested for short duration).

Q.1. How much power can i pull from it with same number of mosfets with 2000VA transformer?

Q.2. How much more mosfets should I connect to pull 2000VA from it. (I can make all pcb traces and wires thicker, its an easy task. Battery bank can deliever 2000w easily)

Comment: Can you give more information?  What voltages are you working with?  Do you have a schematic?

Comment: Battery bank is 12v lead acid.

Comment: Inverter output 220V, 50Hz.

Comment: Transformer has only 2 wires on 12V side and is in H bridge configuration.

Comment: 2 Mosfets at each leg of H bridge. So total 8 mosfets. Mosfets are rated for 110A at 25°C.

Comment: https://goo.gl/images/d92jHm

Comment: Do you have a full schematic?  How are the Mosfet's driven?  Are the mosfets cooled in any way?  Add these details by editing your question instead of posting comments.  Can you add pictures?

Comment: Mosfets are driven according to feedback from 220V side. So you dont need to worry about how they get driven. There is a microcontroller and gate driver ic on board. My questions are simple. Answers are simple as well. Why do you need schematic.

Answer (score 0):

The irf3206 is the best option I could find for you.but you'll have to improve the cooling system and use aric 4 thermal paste.the shunt might need some calibrating.is the an wire wond inductor on the positive leg before it gets to the mosfets?if there is you might need to bridge across it's legs.you might loosing power because of it.